# winium automation: application not responding to winium actions

Tags: automated-tests, jnlp, winium

Currently doing automation for a jnlp application using winium
the application opens and enters the username first but it enters the password but on the gui nothing appears also the click on the login has no effect.
DesktopOptions options = new DesktopOptions();
File driverPath = new File("C:\repo\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");

```
    options.setApplicationPath("C:\\repo\\launch.jnlp");
    options.setDebugConnectToRunningApp(false);
    options.setLaunchDelay(2);

    WiniumDriverService service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(driverPath)
            .usingPort(9999)
            .withVerbose(false)
            .withSilent(false)
            .buildDesktopService();
    driver = new WiniumDriver(service, options);
    try {
        service.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info("Exception while starting WINIUM service");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(15000);

    WebElement webEle_Username = driver.findElementByClassName("Edit").get(0);
    webEle_Username.sendKeys("thabo");

    WebElement webEle_Passname = driver.findElementsByClassName("Edit").get(1);
    webEle_Passname.sendKeys("thabo1234");

    driver.findElement(By.name("Login")).click();

    logger.info("Start...");
```

tried using a different xpath with no effect